# Taking ages to create MSSQL DB on GCE

Tags: windows, sql-server, google-compute-engine

I am setting up infrastructure on GCE and we use MSSQL for DB.

Since now, we used AWS EC2 and it took about 15 seconds to create fresh new SQL database with initial size 50GB on gp2 storage.

If I now try to do the same on GCE it takes about 4 minutes.

I've had tried with same OS version and SQL version as it is on AWS and I've tried with the latest software (WinServer2016 and SQL2016), used SSD persistent disk storage (200GB) and I used instance n1-standard-8 to do it. I've also setup SQL server the same as on AWS.

Any hints why is taking so long to create new DB on GCE?

I know making initial size smaller will speed things up for DB creation but I am worried for DB auto growth.

Best regards,
Matjaz

Answer (score 1):

Loks like it was OS settings issue.

I've added "Perform Volume Maintenance Tasks" rights to SQL server user account and DB was created under 5 seconds on GCE.

More under this url...

https://www.brentozar.com/archive/2014/02/preemptive_os_writefilegather-and-instant-file-initialization-ifi/